# No open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ so that $f|_U :U \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \smallsetminus {0}$ where $f=e^z$ is a bijection

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, branch-points

I nood to show that there is no open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ so that $f|_U :U \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \smallsetminus {0}$ where $f=e^z$ is a bijection.
I started by claiming that for $f$ to be $1-1$, $arg(z)$ must be in the set $[\alpha +2 \pi k,\alpha +4 \pi k)$ for all $z \in U$ for a particular $\alpha \in [0,2 \pi)$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $U$ is contained by a "vertical strip" on the plane, I get nowhere from here.

Comment: Suppose there is a bijection, and $L$ is the inverse of $f$. The function $f$ is analytic, and $f'\not=0$. This implies that $L\colon \mathbb C^*\to U \subset \mathbb C$ is analytic. (Or we can use the inverse function theorem to argue that the bijective $f$ is a local diffeo, and so a global, and thus likewise for $L$.)  Therefore $L$ is  a continuous complex logarithm on $\mathbb C^*$. See the rest of the argument in the "Branches of the complex logarithm" section of  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm